# Ajax results giving undefined values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax result that is formatted in this way:

```
{id: 2850, cap: "50129", citta: "Firenze", provincia: "Firenze", sigla: "FI", …}
```

This is the js I am using:

```
$(function() {
  $('#postal_code').keyup(function ()  {
    if($("#postal_code").val().length == 5) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/addresses/getcitycrovince',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          cap: $("#postal_code").val()
        },
        success:function(result){
          alert(result.sigla);
            $('#province').val(result.provincia);
            $('#city').val(result.citta);
          console.log(result)
        },
        error:function(){
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I need to get values from result but I'm getting `undefined`.
What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT*

this is the getcityprovince function:

```
public function getcitycrovince(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->all();
    $ret = App\CAP::where('cap', $data['cap'])->get();

    return json_encode($ret);
}
```

Comment: Your json response is not valid, should be like `{"id": 2850, "cap": "50129", "citta": "Firenze"}`. Best way to use pre-defined functions to encode your json, also you can always test it [online here](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: What do you receive in alert

Comment: @skobaljic what should I do?

Comment: Put quotes around...

Comment: @KamalPandey I get `undefined`

Comment: could you show code in `addresses/getcitycrovince` which langugage are you using in backend?

Comment: If you're using PHP, than just do `json_encode($response_array)`. Also, not bad to put a header before any output as `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: @skobaljic would go to `error` callback if it wasn't valid json. Something else is wrong

Comment: @DaFois Are you sure that is the only structure returned?  Also **never ever** use `async:false`...it is a terrible practice and is deprecated by browser vendors

Comment: @KamalPandey I've add the function

Comment: could you show the result of `alert(result)` only

Comment: now I get this `[{"id":2850,"cap":"50129","citta":"Firenze","provincia":"Firenze","sigla":"FI","updated_at":"2019-07-12 18:26:17","created_at":"2019-07-12 18:26:17"}]` as answer of the XHR in the browser inspector. The `alert(result)` gives `[object Object]`

Comment: So you have an array not an object returned. That array contains the object you want the properties from

Comment: @KamalPandey alert is not  a practical debugging tool for objects and arrays

Comment: @charlietfl yes it was in his code so i tried to find what he got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting `array` rather than `object` so need to update the code accordingly

```
$(function() {
  $('#postal_code').keyup(function ()  {
    if($("#postal_code").val().length == 5) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/addresses/getcitycrovince',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          cap: $("#postal_code").val()
        },
        success:function(result){
            $('#province').val(result[0].provincia);
            $('#city').val(result[0].citta);
        },
        error:function(){
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```